# Decay of Fourier transform of test functions with fixed support

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Suppose that we have a sequence $u_j\in C_c^\infty(B)$ that satisfies an $L^2$ bound
$$
\sup_j||u_j||_2<\infty.
$$
Here $B$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$.

I speculate that the Fourier transforms $\hat u_j$ have polynomial decay, i.e., there exists $s>0$ such that
$$
\sup_{j,\xi}|\xi|^s|\hat u_j(\xi)|<\infty.
$$
Is this true? Thank you!

Comment: No, this is false in general, the decay of the Fourier transform comes from regularity, but here your sequence of functions can converge to any $L^2$ function supported un the ball. All you can prove for $L^2$ functions is that their symmetric decreasing rearrangement is polynomially decreasing